# android studio can't detect my lib

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, .so

I try to include .so file into my project, here is my gradle :
I create folder for `jnilibs` in this path `src\main\jnilibs` and all of `.so` files to that path.
Folder structure looks like :

```
|--jnilibs
|--|--armeabi
|--|--|--.so Files
|--|--armeabi-v7a
|--|--|--.so Files
|--|--mips
|--|--|--.so Files
|--|--x86
|--|--|--.so Files
```

and then in gradle set code for `jniLibs.srcDirs` and add `compile fileTree`,  my gradle is somthing look like this :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    //....other code
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ["src/main/jniLibs", "$buildDir/native-libs"]
        }
    }

}
task nativeLibsToJar(type: Jar, description: 'create a jar archive of the native libs') {
    destinationDir file("$buildDir/native-libs")
    baseName 'native-libs'
    from fileTree(dir: 'src/main/jnilibs', include: '**/*.so')
    into 'lib/'
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile)
        {
            compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn(nativeLibsToJar)
        }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/native-libs", include: 'native-libs.jar')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar','.so'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
}
```

then rebuild, now i see `native-libs.jar` file in this path : `app\build\native-libs`
So now I want to import lib to my project with this code

```
import org.infradead.libopenconnect.LibOpenConnect;
```

that's all but I get this error now

```
cannot resolve symbol org.infradead
```

Also I was installed `ndk`,`sdk`,`cmake`,`lldb` and os is a `windwos`
whats wrong ? and how can i fix that ?
Kind regards.

Comment: was it solved? i will be glad if you share the result.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try using `File` -> `New` -> `Import module` and load the required files.
2. Next go to `File` -> `Project Structure` -> `app` -> `Dependencies` tab and add the library you added just in recent step.
3. The most important step is, you need to move all your libraries from `build` folder to `app` -> `src` -> `main` -> `libs` folder. This worked for me. Create `libs` folder under `main` if you don't have one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but import mudule is not possible ! or how when i have only lib file without any other gradle ? and also i move all libs from build to libs and in Dependencies add them manually but I don't get any different result